# Best fit 3d transformation with constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, linear-transformations

Given two sets of points, $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$, I know how to find the best fit rigid transformation that will minimize the least squares between the two sets. However, I want to add a constraint to where the absolute difference between a pair of points is $\leq 10$.

I have looked into optimization libraries like CVXPY but I am not familiar with how to set this specific problem up in it or if it is even possible. Any help would be appreciated.